# Legality of Credit Bureaus selling information without consent

Tags: united-states, gdpr, michigan, personal-information, credit-report

I recently had a hard pull for a mortgage done (USA based). Since then, my personal phone number has been bombarded with calls and texts related to "better offers", despite being registered with the do Not Call Registry (USA based). As I have not consented to having my personal information distributed, nor have I consented to the credit bureaus collecting such information, I feel that a law is being broken with how my information got out. Am I wrong in this line of thinking?

<s>Additionally, I am a dual citizen of the USA and Italy. Is there a way for me to leverage GDPR to have this information removed from their records?</s> As per @amon, GDPR does not apply as I and the companies are in the USA.

In the USA, Credit Bureaus are private companies that score you based on many factors to determine how trustworthy you are with other peoples money (for acquiring debt). There is not a good way for an average person to exist without these private companies (mortgages, car loans, etc being tied to their reports), but at the same time, a private company profiting off our information without so much as a hat tip seems, well, wrong.

Comment: Regarding the GDPR sub-question: GDPR won't apply because it cares about *where* you and the data controller are, not what your citizenship is. Since both you and the company are US-based, no EU laws can apply.

Comment: There is specific law permitting credit bureaus to do this sort of thing, part of the FCRA. I will try to convert this into a full answer when I have time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The First Amendment protects the freedom of the press, which generally includes the right to publish information, including personal information, including for profit.

There are laws limiting a company's ability to call you once you're on the Do Not Call list, but a law restricting a credit bureau from publishing your information is generally going to be unconstitutional.